# UserNamePasswordValidator and certificate

Tags: .net, binding, tcp, validation

I have a web service using net tcp binding and custom UserNamePasswordValidator. The username and password are sent by the client in Credentials.UserName.UserName and Credentials.UserName.Password.  My service host is set up as follows:

```
host.Credentials.UserNameAuthentication.UserNamePasswordValidationMode = UserNamePasswordValidationMode.Custom;             host.Credentials.UserNameAuthentication.CustomUserNamePasswordValidator = myCustomValidator;
host.Authorization.PrincipalPermissionMode = PrincipalPermissionMode.Custom;
```

It works perfectly if binding's SecurityMode=TransportWithMessageCredential and ClientCredentialType=MessageCredentialType.UserName are used but that requires a certificate.

I want to make it work without certificate. If I changed to binding's SecurityMode to None, the service started but my UserNamePasswordValidator class was never called.

I tried SecurityMode=Message and SecurityMode.Transport and in both cases, the service required a certificate to start.

Am I missing something? Does custom username and password validator always require certificate?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately WCF doesn't allow you to send a username/password over the wire in plain text. You still can do it, but it requires you create a custom binding like this guy did [here](http://webservices20.blogspot.com/2008/11/introducing-wcf-clearusernamebinding.html). That means that you will have to use a certificate for encryption. Note, this is not the same thing as certificate authentication so don't get confused in that regard. All that it means is that you have to install a certificate which exposes a public key. So your server config will look like so:

```
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="CustomAuthentication">
          <security mode="Message">
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

...

      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="CustomPasswordAuthentication">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpGetUrl="" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <serviceCredentials>
            <serviceCertificate findValue="MyCertificateName" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="Root" />
            <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="MyCompany.WebServices.CustomUsernamePasswordValidator, MyAssembly, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          </serviceCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
```

Client end:

```
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "hello";
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "hello";
client.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.NoCheck;
client.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.PeerOrChainTrust;
client.Open();
```

Hope this helps. EDIT: Just change the wsHttpBinding to TCP or whatever you're using.