# WCF: Use credentials but don't encrypt anything?

Tags: c#, wcf, encryption

We have an application which features different levels of users. This is not a "security feature", this is more to prevent that users change anything that is not related to their role.

Also, the server is not public and only available on local connection(network not accessible from internet).

We would like to use credentials, but we would like that no encryption and ssl is required(because the service has sometimes a lot of data to transfer and we don't want to "loose" time to encrypt/decrypt each time).

Is this possible? What should be used as Security Mode?(we do configure our services in the code, not through XAML).

Thanks

Comment: If the data isn't encrypted, what would stop me 'impersonating' another person (and thus their role) and doing stuff I shouldn't be able to do?

Comment: @mjwills totally agree, but as I said, this is more to help the user than anything else. In my scenario it doesn't make any sense

Answer (score 0):

I would want to know more about the use case you are looking for.

But assuming that you are just trying to prevent anonymous access of an application, you may go for a windows authentication if you are using AD based workstations. If not then you may need to rely on custom authentication which just pops up a challenge before allowing you through.

EDIT: Based on your comment, I understand that you are using CustomUserNameValidator in WCF for auth. Understand that it is not a mandate to use certificate when you are using this. However, certificate improves the security. If you are absolutely sure that your network is protected and snoop-free, you can use self signed certificate using makecert. However, i will always advise to purchase a certificate.

A sample is found here https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pedram/2007/10/05/wcf-authentication-custom-username-and-password-validator/

You can also choose to use  <strike>HTTP</strike> custom binding with plain username / password without any certificate involved

Comment: 1) Not really, we just want an easy way to specify which user level has the right to do what. 2) We already have custom authentication ready, but it seems to ask us certificates.

Comment: Custom auth shouldn't ask for a cert unless you have configured to? What exactly do you mean by custom auth? Can you be more explanatory.

Comment: I'm unfortunately not at work right now, but I'm speaking of this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-use-a-custom-user-name-and-password-validator
What do you mean by "configured to" ?

Comment: Are you sure of what you are saying, this answer seems to suggest otherwise: `Unfortunately WCF doesn't allow you to send a username/password over the wire in plain text.`
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5555512/usernamepasswordvalidator-and-certificate It seems that it always want to use some certificate but that we can make the validation allowing anything.

Comment: Yes, you will need to write a custom binding for the same. WCF will restrict only if you are choosing the binding already defined. I think my last para has a typo.